# Error:(10) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, button

I am new to android development Please help me I got stuck in this ,and here is my question 
When I use button onclick event to call the next activity its showing error message like this "Error:(10) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

This is the code I have written:

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.smartgladiator.myapplication.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@array/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" /></menu>
 </menu>
```

Please help me to do this .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have two `</menu>` closing tags while only one `<menu>` opening tag. Get rid of one of those.